# In UnNethack, how to wake just ONE monster?

Tags: nethack, unnethack

I'm in a room full of sleeping nasties (the Dilapidated armory--rust monsters, disenchanters, brown puddings, etc.). I'm wearing an elven cloak, so walking around doesn't wake them.  But unlike vanilla Nethack, in UnNethack attacking a monster causes a ruckus that awakens the whole room.

So how do I wake just one, so I can lead it out of the room and take care of it out of ear-shot of the others.  It's the disenchanters (and worse) that bother me most.

Comment: I don't think you can. (Where would be the fun in that? :P) You could just leave and come back when you're more prepared.

Comment: You have a point.  It's one of the things that makes UnNethack more...interesting than vanilla Nethack.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to draw an answer to this question from the comment you've already agreed with, you probably **can't**:

> I don't think you can. (Where would be the fun in that? :P) You could just leave and come back when you're more prepared. –
> Doorknob
> Jun 21 '15 at 23:30

> You have a point. It's one of the things that makes UnNethack more...interesting than vanilla Nethack. –
> SMBiggs
> Jun 22 '15 at 15:02